# iOS - How to predefine TextView line height

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextview

I've some `UITextView` declared as the following

```
lazy var inputTextView: UITextView = {
    let tv = UITextView()
    tv.tintColor = UIColor.darkGray
    tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
    tv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    return tv
}()
```

I've been searching **how can I predefine the line height** for this `UITextView` so whenever I write a long text, when it reaches the end of the line and goes to the following line, the **spacing would be bigger than the default.**

I've tried using the following inside the `UITextView` declaration:

```
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 40
let attributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style]
tv.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "", attributes:attributes)
```

Which would become:

```
lazy var inputTextView: UITextView = {
    let tv = UITextView()
    tv.tintColor = UIColor.darkGray
    tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
    tv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    style.lineSpacing = 40
    let attributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style]
    tv.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "", attributes:attributes)
    return tv
}()
```

It only works if I pre-insert some text in the `attributedText` property but since the text is empty in the beginning it will not use those properties and it will be set as default.

How can I increase the default line height and keep it whenever I'm writing in the `UITextView`?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Any tip on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue. The problem was that I shouldn't set the `attributedText` to be set according to the attributes because when we start typing the attributes are gone.

Instead I set the `typingAttributes` to be equal to what I desire so whenever I type in the attributes don't get lost.

Final version:

```
lazy var inputTextView: UITextView = {
    let tv = UITextView()
    tv.tintColor = UIColor.darkGray
    tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
    tv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    let spacing = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    spacing.lineSpacing = 4
    let attr = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : spacing]
    tv.typingAttributes = attr
    return tv
}()
```

Answer (score 1):

Those who are looking for Swift 4 version

```
let spacing = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
spacing.lineSpacing = 7
spacing.alignment = .center
textView.typingAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle.rawValue: spacing,
                             NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]
```

From iOS 11, Apple clears the text attributes after every character. So you have to set the typing attributes in,

```
func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool
```